# What is a real-world practical application for using return false instead of e.preventDefault() and vice-versa?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that if I return false it's essentially calling `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation`.

My question lies in the decision of when I would want to continue event flow vs stopping it altogether. Could we list some real-world situations where I would want to use `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false` and vice-versa to paint a clearer picture for me?

<strike>**EDIT:**</strike>

I'm a visual learner and ***seeing*** *how* something works, as opposed to ***reading*** about it, is how I understand *why* it works. I would be most appreciative to anyone who could post code examples for me.

**EDIT:**

Based on @Pointy's answer and comments, I created a working [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3DwwA/) for those visual learners out there.  I think it sums it up quite nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use "preventDefault()" on a "click" handler for a "submit" button, but not return false.  Why?  Because you may have a "local" handler for the button that makes some decision about whether to proceed with form submission.  However, there may be other handlers set up with ".delegate()" or ".live()", that do other interesting things based on button clicks, so I would want to allow the event to bubble up to those.

*edit* — it's very important to note that the convention of having a `false` return value stop **both** propagation (bubbling) and default behavior is a jQuery thing, and not native.

*edit more* By way of illustration, consider the following HTML:

```
<body>
  <form name='foo' action='whatever'>
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type='submit' value='Go' id='mainSubmit'>
  </form>
</body>
```

Now if I wanted to have some sort of fancy animation happen on any button click on the page, I might have some code that wires that up via ".delegate()":

```
// provide entertaining animation upon button clicks
$('body').delegate('input:submit, input:button, button', 'click', function() {
  $(this).performExcitingAnimation();
});
```

For that submit button in the form, I may want to do form validation to decide whether the form can really be submitted:

```
$('#mainSubmit').click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).closest('form').valid()) return true;
  $('#errorBox').text("Uh oh something is wrong");
  e.preventDefault(); // ... instead of return false
});
```

If that handler had used `return false;` instead of calling the "preventDefault()" method, then the event would not bubble up to the delegated handler and the user would be sadly deprived of some exciting button animation.

Comment: I am almost there following what you are saying.  Could possibly supply working examples of what you are describing?  I'm a visual learner.  Looking at code makes much more sense to me.  (btw I've never had to use live() or delegate(), so I'm not too familiar with them)

Comment: @Scott the reason ".live()" and ".delegate()" are important to the discussion is that they **rely** on event bubbling to work. If you're not yet familiar with those, then most of this topic will seem mysterious.  Those two methods manage event handlers on outer "container" elements (and ".live()" always just uses the `<body>` element), handling bubbled events and matching up the event target with a supplied jQuery selector.  Thus, handlers that break bubbling block those other handlers from doing anything.

Comment: @Pointy - I follow what you are saying, but it just isn't clicking yet.  I really would benefit from a code example.  If you don't have time that's ok.

Comment: @Pointy - Assuming I understand correctly, are we saying that it would be best practice to use `e.preventDefault()` over `return false` in most scenarios and only use `return false` in scenarios where you _know_ that you can safely kill everything?

Comment: I think to be safe, that's a good idea.  However, there are counter-examples. Sometimes you really *want* to stop bubbling, like when you've got a control widget inside another control widget.  I think it's probably best practice to use the more fine-grained explicit methods, but in practice I admit to being lazy and using "return false;" as a shortcut a lot.

Comment: @Pointy - Does this have an affect on chaining in jQuery, either way?

Comment: Chaining?  You mean $(foo).bar().blah().whatever()?  No, it's an unrelated subject.

Comment: @Pointy - Ok, thought so. Last question. After reading up on `live()` and `delegate()`, am I right to say that `delegate()` for the most part replaced `live()`?  Why would you ever use `live()` over `delegate()`?  I know, that's 2 questions, sue me! =D

Comment: Yes you're exactly right - in fact in my opinion ".live()" was a pretty bad idea and should be deprecated. `$(foo).live(event, fn)` is the same as `$('body').delegate(foo, event, fn)`

Comment: @Pointy - Ok, great!  I'm really grasping this concept now. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Pointy - Just thought I'd let you know that I created a nice little jsFiddle demonstrating your answer.  The link is in the question up top.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I use return false in form submits. Sometimes I have forms where I need to ask the user if they want to continue and if they say no I return false to stop the event. There are other variations of those events that are all basically the same thing. You start an event, decide if you don't want to continue, and return false to stop it.